# How to pass json file as parameter to Azure Powershell Runbook?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-runbook, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to deploy sentinel alerts into sentinel using Azure Runbook by using the below command:

```
Import-AzSentinelAlertRule -WorkspaceName "xxx" -SettingsFile "test_alert.json"
```

The SettingsFile of this command expects a path of json as parameter. How we can pass the json file to runbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How we can pass the json file to runbook?

I have reproduced in my environment and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/runbook-input-parameters) and I got expected results as below:

```
Param(
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[object]$json
)
$json = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

[image]

Then save and publish runbook.

Then open your local windows PowerShell and follow below steps:

**Step1:**

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

[image]

**Step2:**

```
 $json =  (Get-content -path "C:Downloads\xy.json") | Out-string
```

[image]

**Step3:**

```
$RBParams = @{
     AutomationAccountName = 'rithwikrunning'
     ResourceGroupName = 'XX'
     Name = 'xy'
     Parameters = $JsonParams
}
```

XX- Name of the resource Group
xy- Name of the runbook

[image]

**Step4:**

```
$job = Start-AzAutomationRunbook @RBParams
```

[image]

Now the json file is passed to run book and it got started:

[image]

Now the content of the file or file is in $json variable in runbook.

**References:**

- [Transferring Microsoft Sentinel scheduled alert rules between different workspaces using PowerShell - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel-blog/transferring-microsoft-sentinel-scheduled-alert-rules-between/ba-p/3269113)

Comment: Hi Rithwik .. Can you please look this link  ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74715980/unable-to-find-type-microsoft-azure-powershell-cmdlets-securityinsights-models