# Unable to find type [Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.SecurityInsights.Models.Api20210901Preview.AutomationRuleRunPlaybookAction]

Tags: powershell, azure-runbook, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to create an automation rule in Sentinel using the below command in Powershell runbook. I have already imported SecurityInsights module of 5.1 version in Runbook. The same command is working fine in VScode Powershell. But I am facing the issue only in runbook.

```
$LogicAppResourceId = Get-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -Name "Reset-AADPassword"
 $automationRuleAction = [Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.SecurityInsights.Models.Api20210901Preview.AutomationRuleRunPlaybookAction]::new()
 $automationRuleAction.Order = 1
 $automationRuleAction.ActionType = "RunPlaybook"
 $automationRuleAction.ActionConfigurationLogicAppResourceId = ($LogicAppResourceId.Id)
 $automationRuleAction.ActionConfigurationTenantId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.Id
 New-AzSentinelAutomationRule -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -WorkspaceName "myWorkspaceName" -Id ((New-Guid).Guid) -Action $automationRuleAction -DisplayName "Run Playbook to reset AAD password" -Order 2 -TriggeringLogicIsEnabled
```

I'm facing the below error:

```
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to find type [Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.SecurityInsights.Models.Api20210901Preview.AutomationRuleRunPlaybookAction].
   at System.Management.Automation.TypeOps.ResolveTypeName(ITypeName typeName, IScriptExtent errorPos)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The property 'Order' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Int32 )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The property 'ActionType' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`3.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The property 'ActionConfigurationLogicAppResourceId' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

I have tried your command and got same error as you got at first:

[image]

Then I have imported `Az.SecurityInsights` from local computer by following below process:

Firstly, Downloaded file from [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.SecurityInsights/3.0.0):

[image]

Then I have imported into run book as below:

[image]

[image]

It took some time to import and download into azure portal:

(Had imported 3 versions didn't know which one worked though and waited for around 30 min and came back)

[image]

Then I added below command into my script at the beginning of your code then rest of the code:

```
Import-Module Az.SecurityInsights
```

Now when i test it and it got completed without errors as below

[image]